# Do I always have to call preventDefault for anchor tags with href='#' in Backbone / Marionette views?

Tags: backbone.js, anchor, marionette, preventdefault

In my Backbone app I have a root route which is just blank. In some of my views I have `<a>` tags for UI elements that I have registered in the view's `events` object. In order to have properly formed markup I need to have `href='#'` in these anchors but I don't want them to go to the root of my app.

It seems like for all `<a>`s that I don't want to go to the root, I have to always call `evt.preventDefault()`. I would like to confirm this and find out if there are other/better options available.

I'm aware I could make a `<div>` or `<span>` with `cursor: pointer` but my gut is telling me I want these to semantically be anchors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three options:

- always return `false` in the handler or call `preventDefault` on the event
- use `href="javascript:void(0)"` (which hurts my eyes)
- place some sort of special class or data attribute on the links that you don't want to be navigable and create some generic handler that always prevents the navigation
- use `<button>` whenever you are using `<a>` with a dummy `href` right now

In my opinion, the last option is the best, because it's clear that these GUI elements perform some action that is 'local' to the content you are showing at the moment, while links (or rather: URIs they link to) are by design representing different resource (and content).

Comment: Thanks! I agree that the last option looks the best. I'll explore this further.

Comment: +1 for using `<button>`s. With how CSS is these days, the markup can truly be left to handle the content structure regardless of the chosen layout or styling.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this recently to an existing project, so I'd like to provide a conditional alternative to the selected answer... Depending on the complexity of the project in question, there is another option that could in my opinion be more efficient.

Quite simply:

- Make it possible to target all applicable links:

  *Example:* add `class="no-link"` to all relevant `<a>` elements.
- Disable typical link functionality by targeting the appropriate CSS selector.

  *Example:* apply the usual `e.preventDefault()` override to elements matching `$('a[href="#"].no-link')`

[JS Bin example.](http://jsbin.com/oruCoQO/1)

That said, most often simpler is better..  If you don't *need* to add a custom class to numerous links on a page, then don't. :) Also be very careful when using this, having insufficiently specific jQuery selectors could result in some links being disabled when you don't expect them to be.